# Continuous open maps on compact sets are surjections.

Tags: general-topology

Could someone help me to show that if $X\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is compact, then every continuous open map $f:X\to S^n$ is surjective?

This question was taken of an Analysis book (the subject of section is connectedness)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about connectedness? Do you understand why you will be done if you show $f(X)$ is both open and closed in $S^n$?

Comment: Is $S^n$ a sphere of dimension n?

Comment: @Mike I know the only subsets of a connected set $Y$ which are open and closed in $Y$ simultaneously are $Y$ and $\varnothing$. Hence, if $f(X)$ is both open and closed in $S^n$ then $f(X)=S^n$ (because $S^n$ is connected). Is it right? Can you give me more details about how to do this?

Comment: @user86828 I think the dimension is not important in this case (because $n$ is arbitrary).

Comment: Yes what you said in your comment is correct. Do you see why $f(X) \subset S^n$ is compact?

Comment: @Mike $f(X)$ is compact because $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuos.

Comment: Yup! And don't forget that a compact subset of a metric space (or Hausdorff space if you like) is closed. Not much further now...

Comment: @Mike As $f$ is open, $f(X)$ is open in $S^n$ (because $X$ is open in $X$). Is it correct?

Comment: Mhm. If you want, you can answer your own question below. That way this question won't stay classified as unanswered, and people can comment on your writeup.

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much. One last question: Is it correct that we can replace $S^n$ by any connected closed set?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In fact, closedness is not needed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f$ is open and $X$ is open in $X$, we conclude that $f(X)$ is open in $S^n$.

As $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, we conclude that $f(X)$ is compcat. But a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is compct if, and only if, it is closed and bounded. So, $f(X)$ is closed (in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and) in $S^n$.

Hence, $f(X)$ is both open and closed in $S^n$. As $S^n$ is connected, the only subsets of $S^n$ which satisfies this condition are $S^n$ and $\varnothing$. Then, $f(X)=S^n$ and $f$ is a surjection.

**Remark:** in this problem we can replace $S^n$ by any connected closed set.

Comment: Looks good to me. The only real issue (and it's a minor one) is that technically $S^n$ sits in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).

Comment: Also, it seems like you have some mild confusion about what is needed for a set to be "relatively closed". If $C,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $C \cap Y$ should be closed in $Y$ (by whatever definition you are using). In particular, if $C \subset Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $C$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: @Mike You're right. It's not necessary $S^n$ be closed to $f(x)$ be closed in $S^n$.